# ASP file being caught by .NET isapi

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, isapi

I need to serve up a few .asp pages from within my ASP.NET site.

This ASP.NET site has a handler that allows us to serve up pages out of the database instead of finding them on disk (where the .asp files are located).

The problem appears to be that the .NET isapi (C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll) is catching my request... at that point, it is going to the database and not finding the file.

My question:  why is ASP.NET catching my request?  I would think it should come in and use the proper extension mapping for .asp (C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll).

Is there a way to tell ASP.NET to leave the .asp files alone?

Comment: BTW - I've tried this with no luck:

<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.pdf"
          type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

Comment: why path="*.pdf"? shouldn't it be path="*.asp"?

Comment: oops.  Copy/paste typo.  I had it right in the web.config.

Comment: @Matt: include additional information by editing your question rather than adding a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one alternative is to set up a virtual directory which only can execute .asp and without asp.net support.

Comment: Good suggestion; however, one problem:  I need to put these .asp files in the root of the site, where a virtual directory wouldn't work.

Comment: have you checked that the site in IIS will execute .asp files?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a wild card script mapping in your application configuration forwarding all requests into the aspnet_isapi.dll.  Is the a .asp mapping to asp.dll?